# parse json file using c#

Tags: c#, json

I need to parse a JSON file using C# into smaller parts.
I would like to know how can I parse the JSON to get each product like below from "product"(since I need to store each smaller json in other places)? What kind of code I need to write?

```
"76V3SF2FJC3ZR3GH" : {
          "id" : "76V3SF2FJC3ZR3GH",
          "attribute1": "AAAAA",
          "attribute2": "BBBBB",
          "attribute3": "CCCCC"        
        }
```

Example of JSON is like:

```
{
  "A" : "XXXXX",
  "B" : "XXXXX",
  "C" : "XXXXXX",
  "D" : "XXXXX",
  "products" : {
    "76V3SF2FJC3ZR3GH" : {
      "id" : "76V3SF2FJC3ZR3GH",
      "attribute1": "AAAAA",
      "attribute2": "BBBBB",
      "attribute3": "CCCCC"        
    },
    "RDXNGJU5DRW4G5ZK" : {
      "id" : "RDXNGJU5DRW4G5ZK",
      "attribute1": "AAAAA",
      "attribute2": "BBBBB",
      "attribute3": "CCCCC"          
    },
......
  }
}
```

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ might also come in handy.

Comment: To deserialize that JSON into fixed c# objects, upload your JSON to http://json2csharp.com, then change `products` into a `Dictionary<string, Product>` along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793347/3744182), and deserialize with [tag:json.net] or maybe [tag:javascriptserializer].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget package and then write:

```
JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyType>(myJsonString);
```

Specifying the type is not mandatory and you can deserialize any json into dynamic object with the same method.

**-- Edit --**

For this case you can use this:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<dynamic>(myJsonString);
```

now `result.products` is an object containing different properties with the names like `"76V3SF2FJC3ZR3GH"` and you can access it like `result.products.76V3SF2FJC3ZR3GH.id`

If you want to get the list of properties you should use Reflection.

Comment: I don't want A, B, C, D. I want each little thing in "products". Then what is MyType refers to? How does Deserialize know what I want is those each little thing?

Comment: Could you please show me some example code? How can I index "products"?

Comment: Please see the edit