# JSON Properties to Array C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
"inputs": {
    "input1": {
        "value": "abc"
    },
    "input2": {
        "value": "cde"
    },
    "input3": {
        "value": "efg"
    },
    "input4": {
        "value": "ghi"
    },      
}
```

Here number of properties in "inputs" may vary. How can I deserialize this into class:

```
class Inputs
{
    public Input[] Values{get; set;}
}

class Input
{
    public string input {get; set;}
}
```

One option is to change the json "inputs" as an array, but I dont have that choice now

Comment: Is your JSON _exactly_ that?  Where `input1`, `input2`, etc are dynamic and could have any number of inputs?

Comment: @maccettura, unfortunately, yes

Comment: Also a duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Deserialize nested JSON into C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793347/3744182).

Answer (score 5):

Your data matches the following data structure.

```
public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

Since you have not mentioned using any library for de/serializing JSON objects, I suggest pretty famous [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library for .Net framework.

In you case you can simply deserialize your data with the following snippet.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
```

Answer (score -1):

How to install

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json:

In Visual Studio, Tools menu -> Manage Nuget Package Manger Solution and type “JSON.NET” to search it online. Here's the figure:

[image]

Then create class with input parameters that you expect to get it as a JSON response.

```
public class Inputs
{
    public string input1 { get; set; }
    public string input2 { get; set; }
    public string input3 { get; set; }
    public string input4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now we will convert it to a .NET object using DeserializeObject() method of JsonConvert class. Here is the code:

```
private void JSONDeserilaize(string json)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Inputs>(json);
}
```

Now you have an object of type Inputs Deserialized successfully

Comment: Please do not give a general not specific for the question example - it does not answer the question. If you want to suggest some library a comment fits best

Comment: The poster specifically asks for how to Deserialize

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer to match rules.

Comment: I do not thin this answer is fully correct. Because OP states that input count can be any number

Comment: Yeah this is just wrong.  Seems obvious the JSON is dynamic, having a class with `input1`, `input2`, etc would not work