# Deserialize nested JSON into C# class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a JSON class like this

```
{
    "Items": {
        "Item_1A": {
            "prop1": "string",
            "prop2": "string",
            "prop3": 1,
            "prop4": [{
                "prop_x": 100
            },
            {
                "prop_y": 200
            }]
        },
        "Item2B": {
            "prop1": "string",
            "prop2": "string",
            "prop3": 14,
            "prop4": [{
                "prop_z": 300
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

How could I make it into C# classes?  Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Info
{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public string prop2 {get;set;}
    public int prop3 {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> prop4 {get;set;}
}
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Info>> Item {get;set;}
}
```

I tried to follow this link, but did not work
[Deserialize nested JSON into C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793151/deserialize-nested-json-into-c-sharp-objects)

Comment: What have you tried already?  What _specifically_ is not working?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is valid JSON, "int" should be in quotes.

Comment: I found the link, and I followed to use Dictionnary<string, List<>> but it returned just null.

Comment: I think the JSON is malformed. There shouldn't be a comma after the square bracket after `"prop_y": int`

Comment: my bad, I just edited

Comment: After a few debugs, I found out the reason for that, but now I got into another one: 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Comment: I'm pretty sure your json is still malformed.  For an easy method check out QuickType, pretty much generates everything for you.  https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: the JSON file is ok, mb I just don't know how to type it correctly here. But now I got into trouble when deserializing it, please help with the new error.

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: Please confirm what serializer you are using.  Most likely it's [tag:json.net] but it might be something else like [tag:javascriptserializer] or [tag:datacontractjsonserializer].

Comment: Try http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model should be as follows:

```
public class Info
{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public string prop2 {get;set;}
    public int prop3 {get;set;}
    // Modified from 
    //public Dictionary<string, List<int>> prop4 {get;set}
    public List<Dictionary<string, int>> prop4 {get;set;}
}

public class Response
{
    // Modified from 
    //public class Dictionary<string, List<Info>> Item {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, Info> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Notes:

- `Response.Item` should have been named `Items`.
- In your JSON, `"Items"` is an object with variably-named object-valued properties:

  ```
  {
      "Items": {
          "Item_1A": { },
          "Item2B": { }
      }
  }
  ```

  This should be modeled as a `Dictionary<string, T>` for an appropriate non-collection type `T`.   Assuming you are using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) see [*Serialization Guide: Dictionaries*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Dictionarys) for details. If not, [javascriptserializer](/questions/tagged/javascriptserializer) behaves similarly.

  Your data model, `public class Dictionary<string, List<Info>> Items`, would have been appropriate for an object with variably-named **array-valued** properties:

  ```
  {
      "Items": {
          "Item_1A": [{ },{ }],
          "Item2B": [{ }]
      }
  }
  ```

  But this is not what you have.
- Meanwhile `"prop4"` is an **array** containing object with variably-named object-valued properties such as:

  ```
  "prop4": [ // Outer container is an array
    {        // Inner container is an object
      "prop_x": 100
    },
    {
      "prop_y": 200
    }
  ]
  ```

  Thus a collection such as `List<T>` should be used as the **outer** generic type:

  ```
  public List<Dictionary<string, int>> prop4 {get;set;}
  ```

  See [*Serialization Guide: IEnumerable, Lists, and Arrays*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Lists).
- As you have noticed, code-generation tools such as those mentioned in *[How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674)* generally cannot recognize JSON objects with variable property names.  In such a situation an auto-generated class may need to get manually replaced with an appropriate `Dictionary<string, T>` property in the containing type.

Sample working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0GhNS0).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip to create proxy classes after a json:

First of all, to make sure it is a valid JSON, go to this website and run the validator: https://jsonlint.com/

If it is ok, there are some tools that convert json and xml to a c# proxy class directly like: http://json2csharp.com/ : https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Now there you go! just copy them to your Model and start using it.

Comment: I know about the converter, but my JSON file can go up to thousands of data. The question is like a sample for 2 keys, what if I have 20000 keys? How could that converter do? 
The reason I asked for that because there was a similar question in the link I posted with above, and the solution was the Dictionary<>, but when I used with mine, I just can't make it work.

Comment: They are different keys values, you know? Or you never read all the info I gave above before comments? How about checking the link I posted with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Just some small changes to your model. Your `prop4` is instead a List or Array.

```
public class Info
{
  public string prop1 {get;set;}
  public string prop2 {get;set;}
  public int prop3 {get;set;}
  public List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>> prop4 {get;set}
}
public class  Response
{
  public class Dictionary<string, Info> Items {get;set;} // Should be named Items
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotabuff/d2vpkr/blob/master/dota/scripts/npc/items.json
may I ask you with this json file for example, am I doing it right with making class?
Or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `prop4` is a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`, which when serialized looks something like this (I've omitted `$type` properties in the emitted JSON for brevity):

```
{
   "X": {
      "$values": [ 1, 2 ]
   },
   "Y": {
      "$values": [ 3, 4 ]
   }    
}
```

Your JSON, while well formed, is "shaped" wrong. It looks more like an array containing a dictionary of one item.

In the JSON above, `X` and `Y` are keys in the dictionary, which is a "regular object" modeled in JSON. The `$values` represents the list of integers for each key.