# Deserialize nested JSON into C#

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I am getting JSON back from an API that looks like this:

```
    [
       {
          "CheckListId":"4",
          "Bphase":"k",
          "ActivityID":"2",
          "FloorTypeId":"216",
          "CheckerId":"",
          "columnFooting":"tets",
          "SubActivityID":"52",
          "columnFootingOTHER":"",
          "rejectFlag":"2",
          "Reportingtype":"Column-Floor",
          "Dphase":"",
          "UserID":"34a86e95-be70-4c6e-84b4-90fc2680cb44",
          "dateTimeSpanCre":"11/13/2018 12:00:00 AM",
          "contractID":"45",
          "UserIdAction":"34a86e95-be70-4c6e-84b4-90fc2680cb44",
          "drawingRef":"testing",
          "ChecklistForId":"683,687,688,689",
          "Aphase":"",
          "projectID":"21",
          "BuildingID":"49",
          "status":"p",
          "DetailsItems":[
             {
                "phase":"b",
                "yesNo":"n",
                "ImageName":"",
                "DoerComments":"",
                "UserId":"34a86e95-be70-4c6e-84b4-90fc2680cb44",
                "base64Img":"",
                "CheckersComments":"",

             },
             {
                "phase":"b",
                "yesNo":"n",
                "ImageName":"",
                "DoerComments":"",
                "UserId":"34a86e95-be70-4c6e-84b4-90fc2680cb44",
                "base64Img":"",
                "CheckersComments":"",

             }
          ]
       },
{
....},
{ ....
}
    ]

I have tried a few approaches

    public class SyncSaveCheckListDetailsMaster
    {
        public string UserID;
        public string CheckListId;
        public string projectID;
        public string contractID;
        public string BuildingID;
        public string columnFooting;
        public string drawingRef;
        public string dateTimeSpanCre;
        public string columnFootingOTHER;
        public string ChecklistForId;
        public string Reportingtype;
        public string FloorTypeId;
        public string status;
        public string rejectFlag;
        public string UserIdAction;
        public string CheckerId;
        public string Bphase;
        public string Dphase;
        public string Aphase;
        public string ActivityID;
        public string SubActivityID;
        public List<List<SyncSaveCheckListDetailsItem>> DetailsItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class SyncSaveCheckListDetailsItem
    {
        public string phase;
        public string yesNo;
        public string DoerComments;
        public string CheckersComments;
        public string UserId;
        public string ImageName;
        public string base64Img;

    }
```

What method i use to desalinize this Nested JSON array

It should be simple, but for some reason I can't figure out the correct

I am very new to web development and I am developing a web app using ASP.NET MVC 5.I have a requirement to deserialize a nested json

Comment: The [method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) you should look into is `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>` And notice that your `DetailItems` should be `List<SyncSaveCheckListDetailsItem>`.

Comment: @ibubi, provided you very clear example of json deserialization, please understand it and implement your code as per the logic. If you are facing any issue there please let us know

Comment: Similar question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793151/deserialize-nested-json-into-c-sharp-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize nested JSON into C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793151/deserialize-nested-json-into-c-sharp-objects)

Answer (score 0):

As **Ibubi** noted; you should change the `DetailsItem` property into `List<SyncSaveCheckListDetailsItem>` and indeed look at NewtonSoft to deserialize the json into an object. You can find details [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm).

Also, this question was asked multiple times before; [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038810/newtonsoft-json-deserialize/17038878).

Comment: Thank u Very much