# Deserialize the Json property(Nested Json) as string in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization, jsonconvert

I need requirement that the deserialize the json as string which is available inside another Json. I have the Json string as like below,

```
string testJson =
   "{
        "AssemblyName":"AssemplyName",
        "ClassName":"AssemplyName.ClassName",
        "Options":"{ "property1":"value1","property2":10}"
   }";
```

To deserialize, I have the class like below,

```
public class CType
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Options { get; set; }
}
```

So, I deserialize like below,

```
CType cType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CType>(testJson);
```

Now, I expect the resuly like below,

```
AssemblyName = "AssemplyName"
ClassName = "AssemplyName.ClassName"
Options = "{ "property1":"value1","property2":10}"
```

It would be much appreciated anyone can help on this

Comment: this is not valid json. can you provie the valid json

Comment: I believe you think about that the option block not a valid one right?. I think that's the problem I have faced. I mean, we have received the Json as a string. So, we need to deserialze the same way. But the JsonConvertor through the error message.

Comment: Check the updated code

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm And use this link to make you Json to Class https://dotnetfiddle.net/WJwvm3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize nested JSON into C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793151/deserialize-nested-json-into-c-sharp-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the class like this.

```
public class Options
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public int property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public Options Options { get; set; }
}
```

Then you caan deserialize and serilize the string like this.

```
string str = "json string";
Example cType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(str);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cType.Options);
```

**Valid Json:**

```
{
    "AssemblyName": "AssemplyName",
    "ClassName": "AssemplyName.ClassName",
    "Options": {
        "property1 ": "",
        "value1": "",
        "property2": 10
    }
}
```

For dynamic nested json you can declare the `Options` as dictionary. Above code will work.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Options { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response vivek. I need to deserailze that option as a string. Because, the options property may changed. I mean, for example, we can received the two property, and some time we receive three. So, we are not able to define the class like above. I'm not sure I correct. But, this is my requirement. Sorry.

Comment: Ok... Thanks vivek. I will check with your idea and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To read options form given json, you need to remove the additional quotations using `Trim` and `DeserializeObject`

```
var cType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CType>(testJson);
var options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(cType.Options.Trim('"'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the options deserialized as a string instead of a dictionary - you would need to change the json file and escape the quotes like below

```
{
"AssemblyName": "AssemplyName",
"ClassName": "AssemplyName.ClassName",
"Options": "
\"property1\":\"value1\",
\"property2\": 10   
"
}
```

With that done your existing code

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string testJson = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.json");

        CType cType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CType>(testJson);

    }
}
public class CType
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Options { get; set; }
}
```

However if you want to make it to another object that is like a Dictionary - the json would need slight change as below

```
{
"AssemblyName": "AssemplyName",
"ClassName": "AssemplyName.ClassName",
"Options": {
"property1":"value1",
"property2": 10
}
}
```

The code would need the property to be changed to Dictionary

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string testJson = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.json");

        CType cType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CType>(testJson);

    }
}
public class CType
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Options { get; set; }
}
```